# Converting Java nested classes to Xamarin.Android

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android

A typical pattern in Android/Java development is to have a nested class that access methods from the parent class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  // implementation

  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    String someString = getString(R.string.thestring);
  }
}
```

So in this case, the `Context.getString()` would be accessing the `MainActivity` context.
How would this convert to `Xamarin.Android` (Mono for Android)?
When trying the exact same pattern I get:

> Error CS0038: Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type
>   `Test.MainActivity' via nested type`
>   Test.MainActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter' (CS0038)

I could of course pass around a Context object, but that seems tedious to do.

Comment: I always extract nested class out and pass `Activity` in a constructor.

Comment: Also, could take a look at section 4.5 of http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/api_design.

Comment: Hmm... that explains it. Write that down as an answer, and I'll accept it

Comment: Thanks. Could you do me a favor? Could you suggest tag `xamarin.android` is a synonym of `monodroid`? I can't do it because I am under 2.5k reputation. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [API design](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/api_design) document of Xamarin.Android:

> Non-static nested classes, also called inner classes, are significantly different. They contain an implicit reference to an instance of their enclosing type and cannot contain static members (among other differences outside the scope of this overview).

So, you should pass a reference of `MainActivity` to `SectionsPagerAdapter`. Then, you could access members of `MainActivity`.

Comment: could you write an example please?

Answer (score 2):

Here an example. I hope it helps.

```
public class YourParentClassActivity : Activity
{
//your stuff 
//...


//The Nested Class (that can implement any interface or base class)
    class YourNextedExampleClass : WebViewClient
    {
        //Parent Class Reference
        private YourParentClassActivity _pc;
        public YourNextedExampleClass(YourParentClassActivity pc)
        {
            _pc = pc;
        }

        public override void OnReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError SSLError)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("xxx");
            _pc.StartActivity(i);
            _pc.Finish();
            handler.Proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }
    }

}
```